# I have better than optimal hardware but Blender keeps crashing

Tags: performance, hardware, system

I am trying to get started using blender and follow a simple tutorial to get used to creating abstract renders for design work.

While running blender even performing the simplest of tasks my computer starts to chug and then eventually crash when trying to add modifications to an object.

Every other program I have run perfectly fine and from what I understand I have more than suitable hardware, so I'm just really confused at this point.

**My Hardware**

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
- GPU: Nvidia Geforce RTX 2060 Super (8GB dedicated + 16GB Shared)
- RAM: 32GB (28 available)

Comment: Does Blender crash or your entire OS? Either way I'd suggest updating your graphics driver, which is the likeliest cause of crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run blender from your system's console, so that when it crashed we can see there what happened eventually.

On windows, open you file explorer and navigate to Blender's installation folder (by default `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender`).
From there, click on the folder path at the top of the explorer, type in "cmd" and hit <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>. It's an easy way to open the console in a specific folder.

[image]

Once here, just type "blender" in the console and hit <kbd>⏎ Entrer</kbd>. It will start Blender as usual, except the console will not close if Blender crashes and will register what happens.

Now, do whatever causes the crash, then look at the console. If you're lucky, the last few lines will tell you very clearly what's the problem and you will be able to solve it yourself in a few clicks and post here what it was.
If you're less lucky, you will have to show us the console's output and we'll see what we can do.

If it's a bug, then it's not something we can handle on this website.

Also, Blender 2.81 just got released, make sure you updated.